# Как использовать переменные $USER и $DB в init.php (1c Bitrix)

Tags: php, битрикс

Пишу регистрацию на 1c Bitrix. Не могу понять как использовать глобальные переменные `$USER` и `$DB` в init.php.

Необходимо после успешной регистрации выполнить sql запросы. Для этого мне необходимо получить id пользователя и соответственно записать данные в БД битрикса.
В `init.php` использую событие `OnAfterUserRegister`. Пытаюсь получить id пользователя, для теста пробовал записать переменную в `$_SESSION` и вывести на экран в файле `registration.php`

**init.php**

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAfterUserRegister","OnAfterUserRegisterHandler");


function OnAfterUserRegisterHandler(&$arFields)
{
    global $USER;
    global $APPLICATION;
    $userId = $USER->GetID();
    $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("myProperty", $userId);
}
```

**register.php**

```
$nameUser = $_SESSION["nameUser"];
echo "nameUser: " . $nameUser;
```

Никакие данные не получаю. Ошибок никаких нет.

Также при выполнении запроса в функции `OnAfterUserRegisterHandler`, появляется ошибка на строке `$dbResult = $DB->Query($strSql);`

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAfterUserRegister","OnAfterUserRegisterHandler");


function OnAfterUserRegisterHandler(&$arFields)
{
    global $DB;
    $strSql = "SELECT * FROM ts_cards ORDER BY cardnum";
    $dbResult = $DB->Query($strSql);
    $card = array();
}
```

Ошибка - **Call to a member function Query() on null**.
Переменная `$DB` имеет значение `null`, я правильно понимаю что ее не видно в данной функции? Почему?
Это тестовые варианты кода, мне необходимо разобраться как использовать данные переменные в файле init.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При регистрации $USER может быть не определён.
Можно попробовать так:

```
function OnAfterUserRegisterHandler(&$arFields)
{
    $userId = $arFields['USER_ID'];
    $_SESSION['USER_ID'] = $userId;
}
```

Вместо `global $DB;` можно попробовать `$DB=$GLOBALS['DB'];`.